# PHP Update Global Variable Using Call From included file - Scoping Issue

Tags: php, scope, global-variables, global

I am trying to implement a simple `add_hook` function using PHP but am coming across some trouble with updating the global array I have to store available/set hooks. If I use `add_hook` from `main.php` it works fine and I can add as many hooks as needed, but if doing the same thing from an included file, the `$hooks` var only updates from within the function.

**main.php**

```
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/functions.php'; 

    $hooks = array();
    function add_hook($hook_name, $function)
    {   
        global $hooks;
        $hooks[$hook_name] = $function;
    }
    add_hook("hook_name", "some_function");


function execute_hook($hook_name)
{
    global $hooks;
    foreach ($hooks[$hook_name] as $function) {
        if (function_exists($function[0])) {
            call_user_func($function[0]);
        }
    }
}

function execute_hooks($hook_name)
{
    global $hooks;
    print_r($hooks);
    if (array_key_exists($hook_name, $hooks)) {
        execute_hook($hook_name);
    }
}

    print_r($hooks); 
    // Array ( [hook_name] => some_function )
    // missing the array added from functions.php
```

**functions.php**

```
add_hook("build_admin_menu", "hd_modify_menu");
```

If I `print_r` at the end of the `add_hook` function, it will print the added hook, but I think the problem is that the "global" `$hooks` does not seem to update with the `add_hook` call from `functions.php`.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and what I can do to fix? Much appreciated!

Comment: If you are doing this to learn php, it's a bad practice to use global variables. Make a class and register the hooks in the class.

If you intend to use this script in a website or something, there are better alternatives already built out there. Search for hook system on packagist or github.

Comment: Because after including the functions.php you are reassigning the $hooks with blank array again hence it resets it again.
check your code below

`require dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/functions.php'; 

    $hooks = array();

Comment: @shashikantkuswaha you are absolutely right. Such a dumb mistake on my part. This is why you shouldn't code so late in the night. Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction

Comment: Your welcome @Harmonic , it happens with everyone. mostly with newbies :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check you code

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/functions.php'; 

   // $hooks = array();
```

The $hook array is reassigned after including functions.php . you need to comment/remove it. as shown above.

Hope this will help you